# dojo - displaying a table with dataGrid when using colspan and rowspan different than 1 in the header

Tags: dojo, html-table, dojox.grid.datagrid

I am trying to create a table using dojox.grid.DataGrid and dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore with the following structure:

```
   |---------------|------------------------------------|
   |               |     COL1.1       |     COL1.2      |
   |  Table Title  |------------------------------------|
   |               | COL2.1 | COL 2.2 | COL2.3 | COL2.4 |
   |---------------|------------------------------------|
   |  ROW_NAME_1   |        |         |        |        |
   |---------------|------------------------------------|
   |  ROW_NAME_2   |        |         |        |        |
   |---------------|------------------------------------|
```

The rowspan and colspan are calculated with an algorithm based on the columns to be displayed in the header. For tables with colspan=1 and rowspan=1 the table is properly displayed. With different values the table is not properly displayed, i.e. I only see the first column of the table containing Table Title and row names. I have the feeling that there is a mismatch or something wrong with the 'field'. Actually, the fld's are assigned within a loop and it is clear what values I should give in the last row of the header (fld0,... fld4) but no idea what values I should use in other rows (I used col11 and col12 in the example below)

```
   <div dojoType="dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore" jsId="stoGrid8" data="{
   "items":[
   {"sortId":"782",
     "fld0":"ROW_NAME_1","attributes0":{"name":"trinput","colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld1":"","attributes1":{"name":"r_orig_245_782","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld2":"","attributes2":{"name":"r_orig_246_782","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld3":"","attributes3":{"name":"r_orig_247_782","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld4":"","attributes4":{"name":"r_orig_248_782","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1}},
   {"sortId":"244",
     "fld0":"ROW_NAME_2","attributes0":{"name":"trinput","colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld1":"","attributes1":{"name":"r_orig_245_244","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld2":"","attributes2":{"name":"r_orig_246_244","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld3":"","attributes3":{"name":"r_orig_247_244","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1},
     "fld4":"","attributes4":{"name":"r_orig_248_244","enabled":1,"colSpan":1,"rowSpan":1}}],
   clearOnClose="true" deferredSave="false" idChap="126901836" 
   controller="./index.php?fuseaction=a.saveencoding">
   </div>

   <table dojoType="dojox.grid.DataGrid" store="stoGrid8" query="{fld0: '*'}"        
   singleClickEdit="false" selectable="true" sort="false" rowSelector="false"        
   columnReordering="false" escapeHTMLInData="false" id="grid8" autoHeight="true" autoWidth="true">
   <thead>
     <tr> 
       <th name='Table Title'width='200px'colSpan='1'rowSpan='2'field='fld0'editable=''/> 
       <th name='COL1.1' width='120px' colSpan='2' field='col11' editable='1' type='dojox.grid.cells._Widget' widgetClass='dijit.form.ValidationTextBox' constraint='{&#39;regExp&#39; : &#39;[\d]&#39;}'/> 
       <th name='COL1.2' width='120px' colSpan='2' field='col12' editable='1' type='dojox.grid.cells._Widget' widgetClass='dijit.form.ValidationTextBox' constraint='{&#39;regExp&#39; : &#39;[\d]&#39;}'/>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
       <th name='COL2.1' width='120px' colSpan='1' field='fld1' editable='1' type='dojox.grid.cells._Widget' widgetClass='dijit.form.ValidationTextBox' constraint='{&#39;regExp&#39; : &#39;[\d]&#39;}'/> 
       <th name='COL2.2' width='120px' colSpan='1' field='fld2' editable='1' type='dojox.grid.cells._Widget' widgetClass='dijit.form.ValidationTextBox' constraint='{&#39;regExp&#39; : &#39;[\d]&#39;}'/> 
       <th name='COL2.3' width='120px' colSpan='1' field='fld3' editable='1' type='dojox.grid.cells._Widget' widgetClass='dijit.form.ValidationTextBox' constraint='{&#39;regExp&#39; : &#39;[\d]&#39;}'/> 
       <th name='COL2.4' width='120px' colSpan='1' field='fld4' editable='1' type='dojox.grid.cells._Widget' widgetClass='dijit.form.ValidationTextBox' constraint='{&#39;regExp&#39; : &#39;[\d]&#39;}'/>
     </tr>
   </thead>
```

Any ideas about what is wrong?

Comment: I have just found out this: